# Hypergeometric Transformation Proof

Tags: analysis, power-series, hypergeometric-function

I would like to proof the following identity:

$$\frac{n z}{\Gamma(3/2-n)} \, _2F_1\left(2,1-n;\frac{3}{2}-n;z\right)=\left[\,
   _2F_1\left(1,-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;z\right)-\, _2F_1\left(2,-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;z\right)\right] \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2-n)}$$

I attempted in this way. Since a known property is:

$$(z (c-b)-a) \, _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b;c;z)+z (a-c) (c-b) \, _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b;c+1;z)=a (z-1) \,
   _2\tilde{F}_1(a+1,b;c;z)$$

where $\, _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b;c;z)=\, _2F_1(a,b;c;z)/\Gamma(c)$. Setting $a=2$, $b=1-n$ and $c=1/2-n$, I obtained:

$$\, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(2,1-n;\frac{3}{2}-n;z\right)=-\frac{2 \left((z+4) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(2,1-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;z\right)+4 (z-1) \,
   _2\tilde{F}_1\left(3,1-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;z\right)\right)}{(2 n+3) z}$$

Now recalling the property:
$$\,
   _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b;c;z)=\frac{(b-c
   -1) }{(b-1)
   (z-1)}\,
   _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b-2;c;z)+\frac{(z (-a+b-1)-2 b+c+2)
   }{(b-1)
   (z-1)}\,
   _2\tilde{F}_1(a,b-1;c;z)$$

setting $a=1-n$, $b=3$ and $c=1/2-n$ I obtained:

$$\, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(2,1-n;\frac{3}{2}-n;z\right)=-\frac{2}{z} \left[\, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(1,1-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;z\right)+(z-1) \,
   _2\tilde{F}_1\left(2,1-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;z\right)\right] $$

From this point on I don't know how to proceed, any idea?

Comment: If $n \in \mathbb N$, then the lhs of the first identity is $z \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} a_k z^k$ and the rhs is $\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k z^k$ with $a_{k - 1} = b_k$.